# How to stop Azure function app container started from Azure cloud shell?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-shell

Using Azure cloud shell to make changes and test locally. After changes are made, starting function app container using `func start --verbose`. Before making further changes and test again, need to stop the container first. What is the recommended way to do it? Tried ctrl+c, ctrl-z it takes about ~5 mins to ~12 mins everytime and then control returns to the prompt.

Stuck in terminating after printing the following logs

```
[2022-08-11T07:28:16.777Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=515.
[2022-08-11T07:28:16.777Z] python3 exited with code 1 (0x1). .
[2022-08-11T07:28:16.778Z] Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:python. Shutting down and proactively recycling the Functions Host to recover
```

Answer (score 0):

The `func start` command is used to run the function. In a background it will trigger function required components like configurations, host, port, etc.,

Whenever we change any configuration in a function the function and container will restart.

If we run the function, it will allocate specific resources and required packages & files. If stop the function in between it will reallocate the resources and release the file components. So, it will take some time to release the control to the prompt.

> Before making further changes and test again, need to stop the container first. What is the recommended way to do it?

You can **[build the container image environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process,bash,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-csharp#build-the-container-image-and-test-locally)** to test it **locally**. Keep your Dockerfile in root project it will gives the required environment to run the **Function App in a container**.